# Saving multiple pairwise correlation plots in a pdf via for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, pdf, plot, save

I am trying create multiple pairwise correlation plots (pairs.panels from the psych package is the function i use) by looping over a list of datasets and saving that in multiple pdfs with changing names. It can also be one pdf with titles (I dont get the main = "xyz" function in pairs.panels to run). 
It can also be another format (jpeg, png...whatever)

My dataset (called "df" here) has 8 variables, one of which is a grouping variable (hence the "group" variable). I want a correlation matrix of the variables 2 to 7, for each group one plot (I know these look terrible here, my skills in simulating data are terrible). The dataset (df2) is a list of datasets (here its only 3), I just devided the dataset df by group.

I tried using the pdf() function inside and outside the loop, using two loops, one for creating the graphs and one for the pdf device, I tried making a list of graphs and using that...

I can get the plot to run, I can save the plot, if I use the corresponding numbers 1,2,3 etc in the brackets instead of i, which makes me think its something with the loop. 
If you have some kind of explanation for what I need to do, that would be great!

```
# shitty data simulation
set.seed(16)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
                    x = rnorm(n = 9, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                    y = rnorm(n = 9, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                    z = rnorm(n = 9, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                    a = rnorm(n = 9, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                    b = rnorm(n = 9, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                    d = rnorm(n = 9, mean = 0, sd = 1))

 df2 <- as.list(split(df, df$group))

 for(i in 1:3){ # setting the loop for the pdf device

 pdf(paste("myplot", i, ".pdf"), onefile = F) # opening the device, plots are calles plot1, plot2 etc.

 for(i in 1:length(df2)){
 pairs.panels(df2[[i]][,c(2:7)], stars = TRUE, pch = ".")
 mtext(side = 3, line = 3, df2[[i]]$group) # the only option I manage to get a header in there
 }
dev.off()
}
```

I either cannot open the file (sometimes it takes hours to finish and then I only get 2 plots). I usually dont get error messages pertaining the loop (only the correlations, but that I know already and some of the variables have missing data, it still can print the plot). 
Sometimes I get a big file with one plot multiple times and no title. and sometimes its just corrupted.

Comment: What is `test2`? Please provide `dput(test2)`, make a [mcve].

Comment: You are using `i` iteration in both `for` loops

Comment: I tried to provide some sample data, does this help?